# SIM contacts won't show up

Tags: 8.0, contacts

I'm trying to move contacts from an Android phone to a WP8 device.

On the Android device I backed-up all my contacts to the SIM card.

On the WP8 device I went to People -> Settings -> import SIM contacts, but I find that there's only a handful of contacts listed, and those contacts are things like "Voicemail inbox" and "Customer care".

I've been back to the Android device to double-check that the contacts *have* been backed-up to the SIM.

What am I doing wrong?

Are there different standards for storing contacts on SIM cards? Is the Android device backing up GMail contacts rather than phone numbers?

What should I do to get the numbers from one device to the other?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to import all your contacts from your old phone via Bluetooth; for example using the [Transfer my Data](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02) app.

Comment: I did try this yesterday and although it said that it had transferred 210 contacts, none appeared in the list of contacts.  
However, this morning the numbers mysteriously appeared in the list of contacts.

Answer (score 1):

**Question** : Are there different standards for storing contacts on SIM cards?
**Answer** : No. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module#SMS_messages_and_contacts

**Question** : What should I do to get the numbers from one device to the other?
**Answer** : Sync with Google Account is an option.

Please verify that these SIM contacts are available on anyother device.